# Hibernate search. How to exclude entity from index?

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor, hibernate-search

I am new at hibernate search and I need to use it with my application database.
I have a couple of indexed entities classes and I want exclude some entities from index based on their state. I my case I want to exclude objects with template == null I have found [this feature](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-search-mapping-indexinginterceptor-blog)  and implemented it but this interceptor not working\invoking

This is what I have

```
public class WorkDocumentInterceptor implements EntityIndexingInterceptor<WorkDocument> {

@Override
public IndexingOverride onAdd(WorkDocument workDocument) {
    System.out.println("on ADD workDocument = " + workDocument.getId());
    if (workDocument.getTemplate() == null) {
        System.out.println("SKIP DOCUMENT " + workDocument.getId() + ":" + workDocument.getTitle());
        return IndexingOverride.SKIP;
    }
    return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
}

@Override
public IndexingOverride onUpdate(WorkDocument workDocument) {
    if (workDocument.getTemplate() == null) {
        return IndexingOverride.REMOVE;
    }
    return IndexingOverride.UPDATE;
}

@Override
public IndexingOverride onDelete(WorkDocument workDocument) {
    return IndexingOverride.APPLY_DEFAULT;
}

@Override
public IndexingOverride onCollectionUpdate(WorkDocument workDocument) {
    return onUpdate(workDocument);
}
```

}

Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_document")
@Indexed(interceptor = WorkDocumentInterceptor.class)
public class WorkDocument implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    Template template;
    ...  
}
```

When indexing is running I even do not see this output, it seems interceptor not invoking

```
System.out.println("on ADD workDocument = " + workDocument.getId());
```

To rebuild index I call this

```
            em.createIndexer(clazz)
                    .purgeAllOnStart(true)
                    .optimizeAfterPurge(true)
                    .optimizeOnFinish(true)
                    .batchSizeToLoadObjects(25)
                    .cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
                    .threadsToLoadObjects(5)
                    .threadsForIndexWriter(3)
                    .threadsForSubsequentFetching(20)
                    .startAndWait();
```

Why it does not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial version of conditional indexing did now work with the mass indexer. This got addressed in Hibernate Search 4.2.0.Final. The issue is tracked under https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HSEARCH-1190

Comment: Hardy, thanks for reply, I don't know how but I have missed out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I spent half a day to find solution.

Just change hibernate-search version from **4.1.1** to **4.2.0**

Interceptor works as expected